# SAS - Extract Signed Float from String

Tags: sas

I have a SAS dataset with character field containing a sequential series of signed integers that I can easily extract with the SCAN() function nested inside INPUT (to convert to best6. numeric) and COMPRESS (to handle some seemingly randomly occurring spaces), but I can't figure out how to keep the negative sign, which appears in about half my records.

Field example: "Result quantity1 = -139 quantity2 = 458 ..."
So, in the above example of the field, I'd extract token 4 and get 139. My problem is that my code like:

```
resultNumber = input(compress(scan(charField,4),''),best6.);
```

.. results in 139 instead of -139. Appreciate any advice, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to tell the `SCAN()` function call what characters to use as delimiters.

```
data _null_;
  charField="Result quantity1 = -139 quantity2 = 458 ...";
  resultNumber = input(compress(scan(charField,4,' '),''),best6.);
  put (_all_) (=);
run;
```